# if statement with 'or' operator gives different results when conditions are swapped

Tags: matlab, string-comparison, logical-operators

I'm using `strfind` with an 'or' comparison like so:

```
name='hello';
if strfind(name,'hello') | strfind(name,'hi')
    disp('yes!')
end

>> yes!
```

The `if` statement must evaluate as `true`, since `yes!` is displayed.

In contrast, MATLAB doesn't return `yes!` if the statements are swapped:

```
if strfind(name,'hi') | strfind(name,'hello')
    disp('yes!')
end
```

Why?

Comment: You've got two good answers already, but I wanted to add that you should always try to use expressions that evaluate to either `true` or `false` in an `if` statement. It prevents a lot of difficult bugs. MATLAB will do what sometimes is perceived as illogical when the expression in an `if` statement is not a scalar Boolean value. `strfind` returns a vector with starting indices, not a Boolean scalar. That right there tells you something is off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the following conditions are empty `[]`:

```
name='hello';
strfind(name,'hello') | strfind(name,'hi'); % = []
strfind(name,'hi') | strfind(name,'hello'); % = []
```

As referenced in [Ander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177725/3978545), the `|` operator is using [short circuiting](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) to skip evaluation of the second condition if the first is false (or empty).

Some quick debugging will give you better understanding if we ignore short-circuiting:

```
strfind(name,'hi');    % = []
strfind(name,'hello'); % = 1
```

In both cases you are doing "if empty or non-zero", which is empty and "`if []`" is false (that conditional statement won't be executed).

What you want to use to be explicit is something like this:

```
if ~isempty(strfind(name, 'hello')) & ~isempty(strfind(name, 'hi'))
    disp('yes!')
end
```

Here, we guarantee that everything being evaluated in the `if` statement is a Boolean variable, not empty or an index like `strfind` returns, so unexpected results are less likely.

There are simpler methods, like using `strcmp` or `ismember` if your strings should match exactly. Or [`contains`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html) if you have R2016b or newer:

```
if contains('hello', {'hello','hi'})
    disp('yes!');
end
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because short-circuiting. Short-circuited logical operators are a thing to speed up code. You can have

```
if veryShort | superlongComputation
```

so what MATLAB does is first evaluate `veryShort` and if it is true, then no need to evaluate the second one! The if condition is already met.

In your case `strfind(name,'hello')` returns `1`, but `strfind(name,'hi')` returns `[]`.

In the first example, as the first thing evaluated returns `1`, you get to the display. However in the second case, it returns `[]`, therefore MATLAB evaluates the second thing in the `if`, and returns `1`. Then MATLAB applies the `or` operations where `[] | 1` is an `0x0 empty logical array`, so the `if` is not true.

Note, generally you want to use `||` to enforce short-circuiting, but `|` also does it, if it is inside a `while` or an `if`:

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99518-is-the-logical-operator-in-matlab-a-short-circuit-operator

Comment: Interestingly, the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) suggest short circuiting is only a thing for the double operators (`&&` and `||`), I find that both of the examples using only `|` return false...

Comment: @Wolfie I noticed, but the behavior OP shows is indeed happening. It may be that perhaps `||` short circuits always, while being in an `if` statement triggers some JIT short-circuiting? It definitely happens.

Comment: Cheers, I've linked to your answer and expanded on my own - think we got everything covered between us!